# Ruby on rails, Solidus e-comerce, problem with google indexing

Tags: ruby, indexing, ruby-on-rails-5, google-search-console, solidus

Google indexing stopped on my site with error like

```
"invalid value type for "name" field.
```

The rails code generating this HTML is

```
<% if products.any? %>
  <ul id="products" class="inline product-listing" data-hook>
    <% products.each do |product| %>
      <% url = spree.product_path(product, taxon_id: @taxon.try(:id)) %>
      <li id="product_<%= product.id %>" class="columns three <%= cycle("alpha", "secondary", "", "omega secondary", name: "classes") %>" data-hook="products_list_item" itemscope it
emtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <% cache(@taxon.present? ? [I18n.locale, current_pricing_options, @taxon, product] : [I18n.locale, current_pricing_options, product]) do %>
      <div class="product-image">
        <%= link_to(render('spree/shared/image', image: product.gallery.images.first, size: :small, itemprop: "image"), url, itemprop: 'url') %>
      </div>
      <%= link_to(truncate(product.name, length: 50), url, class: 'info', itemprop: "name", title: product.name) %>
      
      <span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <% if price = product.price_for(current_pricing_options) %>
          <span class="price selling" itemprop="price" content="<%= price.to_d %>">
            <%= price.to_html %>
          </span>
        <% end %>
        <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<%= current_pricing_options.currency %>"></span>
      </span>
    <% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

The page displays fine but does not index on in google. How can I fix this? do I have a syntax error of so in the rails code? I don't see one. what could be causing this?

Comment: Look at the error closely. There is something not right with the `name` of at least one value. You need to review them and see which one is the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by rewriting the rails code wrapped in html header tags like below:

```
 <h6 style="color:Black;" class="info" itemprop="name">
    <%= link_to(truncate(product.name, length: 50), url, title: product.name) %>
  </h6>
```